# Xcode Swift application deployed to iphone losses CoreData after iPhone reboot

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

My simple Swift application uses an SQLite DB in CoreData for table view data.  I deployed the app to my iPhone via the simulator.  After a reboot of the iPhone the persistent data was no longer present....but the application launches.  What must I do to keep the data persistent?
IOS9.2.1 & Swift 2.0

Comment: Make sure to save the core data context, usually by calling context.save()

Comment: Where are you saving the data store? If you are saving it in the caches directory that's your problem. It belongs in Documents.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's interesting about CoreData is that it isn't a database. It's a wrapper around a data store, in your case SQLite.

If you don't tell CoreData to save it's contents, it *will never write the changes to disk.*

Calling `save` on your NSManagedObjectContext will do the trick. :)

There are other reasons that it wouldn't persist, but I would check this first.