# Core data do not retain database after iPhone reboot

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using Swift 2.2 iOS 9.3.1 and 9.3.2 (beta) iPhone 5s and 6s.

When running the simulator with iPhone 5s and 9.3, Core Data retains the database after a reboot. But not when run on the physical devices.

I've made a very simple to-do app to learn more Swift and now Core Data. I've followed some tutorials as 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial and [Apples Core Data Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html).

This SO [Xcode Swift application deployed to iphone losses CoreData after iPhone reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853065/xcode-swift-application-deployed-to-iphone-losses-coredata-after-iphone-reboot) have what looks like the same issue, but little activity. Hoping that bringing more info to the table would help with my issue.

I do save the MOC when the app enters background and when it terminates. I'm calling this function in my DataController and observing that it prints the expected text.

```
func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                print("DataController saveContext")
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

I am saving to the Documents directory as suggested by others.

```
...
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
...
```

I've tried googling this for several hours but I can't wrap my head around why this should happen. But my googling skills just ain't strong enough or I'm just overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function and after iphone reboot I still have my datas.

```
// Save data to CoreData
func saveLocalUserProfile(variables, ....) {
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Create the core data object
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("YourTable", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let userProfile = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Set datas
    userProfile.setValue(variable, forKey: "varaible")
    ....

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // Save data into Core Data
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("Save ok")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see that I'm doing things very differently. Guess I'll write a even simpler app to see if this problem persists. I'll also try to find an iPhone with an earlier version of iOS. Thanks.